# how to join three table on base of ncarpk in mysql

Tags: mysql, sql

I want check ncarpk in tour_customer, tour_provider, reservation if any table have record with ncarpk = 7, then show result.

```
select *
from tour_customer
    Left Outer join tour_provider on tour_provider.nCarPk = '7'
    Left Outer join reservation on reservation.nCarPk = '7' 
where tour_customer.ncarpk = '7'
```

Comment: You should edit your question to explain what you expected to happen, and what happened instead.

Comment: Could you include desired output?

Answer (score 0):

i would try

```
select *
from tour_customer
Left Outer join tour_provider on tour_provider.nCarPk =customer.ncarpk     
Left Outer join reservation on reservation.nCarPk = customer.ncarpk  
where tour_customer.ncarpk = '7'
```

This is the normal way to make joins, you say on which field you want to make the join and then you add the where clause.

Comment: i have constant ncarpk  and is 7 . now i want to join all three table if any one have ncarpk is 7 then result appeer. if all table are not having ncarpk then result show none

Comment: could you please Show some sample data and the desired Output. Perhaps i didn't understand well your problem

Answer (score 0):

Well it is ugly without full join in mysql. You can use unions instead:

```
Select t1.id,t2.id,t3.id from
t1 left outer join t2 on t1.id = t2.id
left outer join t3 on t1.id = t3.id
where t1.id = 7 or t2.id = 7 or t3.id = 7
union
Select t1.id,t2.id,t3.id from
t2 left outer join t1 on t1.id = t2.id
left outer join t3 on t2.id = t3.id
where t1.id = 7 or t2.id = 7 or t3.id = 7
union
Select t1.id,t2.id,t3.id from
t3 left outer join t2 on t3.id = t2.id
left outer join t1 on t1.id = t3.id
where t1.id = 7 or t2.id = 7 or t3.id = 7
```

Here is fiddle http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/f4576/2 .
Change to your tables instead of `t1,t2,t3` and change `id` with `nCarPK`.